# How to store/read string on MIPS?

Tags: string, assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I'm having trouble reading a string that previously was introduced by the user and saved in memory.
The function to read the string:

```
.data
table:     .space    1200
buffer:    .space    30

empty:     .asciiz    "The string is empty\n"

.text
la $t7,table
li $s4,0

li $v0, 8
la $a0,buffer
li $a1, 30
syscall

move $t0,$a0
move $a0,$t0    # parameter
jal insert
```

Then using the readed string, I pass through $a0 as a parameter to another function that stores the string to a certain memory position (with 60 bytes space within each string).

```
insert:     mul $s6,$s4,60      # padding (index*padding)
            add $t7,$t7,$s6     # address of the next free position
    
            sw $a0,0($t7)
    
            addi $s4,$s4,1
```

Also I've got a function that given an index (introduced by the user as an integer), recovers the string stored in that position (if is not empty):

```
read_table: move $t5,$a0        # a0 contains the index as a parameter
            la $t4, table
            mul $t5,$t5,60      
            add $t4,$t4,$t5     
    
            lw $s1,0($t4)       
            beqz $s1,empty_str
    
            li $v0,4
            move $a0,$s1
            syscall


empty_str:  li $v0,4
            la $a0,empty
            syscall
```

My problem comes when regardless of the index I enter, the program always return the last string introduced by the user although it seems to be stored properly. I understand that it might be some misuse of the buffer, but any of the solutions I've thought worked.

[**EDIT**] Here goes the whole code block to clarify the question, as suggested (supposing that all the data that the user introduces is OK):

---

):

```
    .data
    table:     .space    1200
    buffer:    .space    30

    empty:     .asciiz    "The string is empty\n"
    
               .text
               la $t7,table
               li $s4,0
   main:       li $v0,4
               la $a0,tira1
               syscall

               li $v0,5
               syscall
        
               beqz $v0,index    # If 0, read from table, 1 insert to the table
               beq $v0,1,string
                
  string:       li $v0, 8
               la $a0,buffer
               li $a1, 30
               syscall
    
               move $t0,$a0
               move $a0,$t0    # parameter
               jal insert
    
    index:     li $v0,5        # function to get index
               syscall
               move $a0,$v0
               jal read_table
 


    insert:    mul $s6,$s4,60       # padding (index*padding)
               add $t7,$t7,$s6      # address of the next free position
        
               sw $a0,0($t7)
        
               addi $s4,$s4,1
               b main


    read_table: move $t5,$a0        # a0 contains the index as a parameter
                la $t4, table
                mul $t5,$t5,60      
                add $t4,$t4,$t5     
        
                lw $s1,0($t4)       
                beqz $s1,empty_str
        
                li $v0,4
                move $a0,$s1
                syscall
                b main


    empty_str:  li $v0,4
                la $a0,empty
                syscall
```

Comment: There's too much missing code to analyze in detail.  Suggest maybe to post the whole thing in one code block.

Comment: @ErikEidt Done! Although I'm still thinking that the main issue is related to the string management

Comment: @ErikEidt precisely, what it happens is that despite I'm able to read multiple strings, buffer address is always pointing to the last string written so the last one is the only string stored within all positions (i.e. "test1" is stored at index 0, but if I enter another string will occupy both positions at index 0 and 1. And so on...)