# Counting number of letters and printing them out in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

as the title says I am stuck on with getting the code to be able to accept input from the user and printing the amount of characters out.

I have message instead of input in the .data and .main ( the message is where I have to write the message or string out manually in the code)
I instead want to use input so that the user should be able to enter the string in the input/output box. For instance the sentence One man two men has 15 characters, so that portion of the code is working fine, the only issue I have is getting the .input from the user working, any ideas on how I should add that to the code?

the code looks like this;

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "One man two men"
.text

main:
    li $t1,0
    la $t0,message

loop:
    lb   $a0,0($t0)
    beqz $a0,done
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    addi $t1,$t1,1
    j     loop
done:

    li   $v0,1
    add  $a0, $0,$t1
    syscall

    li   $v0,10
    syscall
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am using the mars simulator or program. If that is a factor in the code or solution.

Comment: There's  a syscall for string input from the user. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling from this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203587/how-to-store-read-string-on-mips

As in this code, you should be able to use the `read` system call to read input from stdin (on Linux, automatically fd 0 in a terminal process). If you like, you can first issue a prompt using the `write` system call on stdout, which is fd 1.

You will have to manage the memory into which you read. The cited example puts it in a buffer of hardcoded length. If you don't need to store the string, you can simply read one byte at a time until there are no more bytes. `read` returns the number of bytes read, so you should be able to count the number of bytes in the input as you go.

Note that unless you change some options on stdin you will not receive any bytes until the user hits "enter", and your input will include the terminating newline character.

Comment: Most MIPS questions on Stack Overflow are about MARS/SPIM, where the simulated system has a set of toy system calls provided by the simulator (https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html), which do things that would be libc function calls on Linux or Windows.  e.g. `syscall` with `$v0=1` is print-integer, of the value in `$a0`.  MARS *does* have file descriptors for read/write binary data, but normally student programs are expected to use the read-string call that takes a buffer and length, implicitly reading from the MARS UI's console.

Comment: If you want to read 1 char at a time, there's `$v0=12` which is like getchar.  AFAIK there isn't a way in MARS to change the terminal to raw mode, so you're always stuck with trailing newlines.  And the read-string toy syscall fills your buffer with a `0`-terminated string, not bothering to tell you how many bytes were actually read.  (The `$v0=14` read-from-file syscall may be usable with fd=0, I haven't tried.)

Comment: Of course, I was talking about Linux, not the MARS simulator. It does make a difference, my answer doesn't seem to quite fit with the MARS syscalls. Thank you @PeterCordes!

Answer (score 0):

This program will count letters from the given string.
The code is commented, if there is more to be explained let me know.
First it will count the number of chars (not letters) from the `message` then from `message1` which is a string read from the keyboard.

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "One man two men"
    enterTheMsg: .asciiz "\nEnter the message: "
    message1: .space 100
.text

main:
    la $a0,message
    jal countLetters 
    
    move $s0 ,$v0        #same returned value
    
    li   $v0,1           #print integer
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, enterTheMsg
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 8            #read string
    la $a0, message1
    li $a1, 30           #maximum numbers of chars to be read 30 
    syscall 
    
    la $a0, message1
    jal countLetters
    move $s0 ,$v0        #same returned value
    
    li   $v0,1           #print integer
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall
            
    j endOfProgram

countLetters:
    move $t0, $a0         #message base address
    li $t1,0              #index 
    li $t4,0              #counter
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

loop:
    add  $t3, $t1, $t0    #calculate element memory address in message
    lb   $t2,0($t3)
    beqz $t2,countLetters_exit    #if end of string done
    
    beq  $t2, 10, loop_next          # will not count \n
    addi $t4, $t4, 1                 #counter increment

loop_next:    
    addi $t1,$t1,1        #increment index   
    
    j     loop
    
countLetters_exit:
    move $v0, $t4         #move the counter to return register
    jr $ra                #return from function

endOfProgram:
    li   $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: This counts all non-newline characters.  Including spaces and punctuation.